# configuring codeship via code

Tags: python, web-scraping, codeship

I couldn't find any API to configure my codeship project :(
I have multiple repositories, and would like to allow the following steps programatically:

1. List repositories of my team
2. create a new repo pipeline (for each microservice I have a seperate repo)
3. Edit pipeline steps scripts for newly created project (and for multiple projects "at once")
4. Customize a project's environment variables
5. delete an existing project

Is there any way to do it?
How do I authenticate?
Even if I have to do by recording network curls - is there a better way to authenticate other than pasting an existing cookie I copy from my own browsing? OAuth, user-password as header, etc.?

I'm trying to write a python bot to do it, but will take any example code available!

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed your question here on SO and figured I'd answer it here as well as your support ticket (so others can see the general answer).

We're actively working on a brand new API that will allow access to both Basic and Pro projects. The target for general availability is currently at the beginning of Aug '17. We'll be having a closed beta before then (where you're on the list)